# SDK Path not specified

Tags: android, android-testing, spoon

Steps I did

1. Downloaded Runner JAR and Client JAR from [Square](http://square.github.io/spoon/)
2. Copied `spoon-client-1.1.2.jar` to the libs folder, right click --> Add As Library...
3. wrote a simple dummy test:

   ```
   public MainActivityTest() {
       super(MainActivity.class);
   }

   public void test() {
       Spoon.screenshot(getActivity(), "initial_state");
   }
   ```
4. Ran MainActivity
5. Ran MainActivityTest (Tests passed)
6. Copied `app-debug.apk` and `app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk` from the project to the same folder as the `spoon-runner-1.1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
7. CMD -> switched to the folder where I put the three files
8. Executed `java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk app-debug.apk --test-apk app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk`

---

**Output:** `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: SDK path not specified. at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull<Preconditions.java:226> at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner$Builder.setAndroidSdk<SpoonRunner.java:228> at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.main>SpoonRunner.java:437>`

The SDK is located in `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` and I can see the path under: File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location (Android Studio)

What went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the **Android SDK path**. However specify the path did the trick. The full command looks like:

```
java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk app-debug.apk --test-apk app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk --sdk C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Comment: I am able to run spoon successfully and can see spoon output but there are no screenshots with test failures. I did not add spoon-client.jar in the instrument test app. Do I need it to get screenshots if yes where Taking screenshots requires that you include the spoon-client JAR in your instrumentation app. Where to add spoon-client in Android Studio?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the PATH environment variable for java.

In windows is somethink like this:

PATH = PATH + "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24"

Then restart ADT and SDK Manager.exe

Try to check what is the jdk you use in ADT. Go to Project -> Properties ->Java Compiler

Comment: the system environment variable `PATH` is already set and also `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: The execution of the command `java -version` gives me the output `java version "1.8.0_25"` which is also defined in the project (Java Compiler 1.8). By the way I use Android Studio (IntelliJ) instead of Eclipse with the ADT Plugin.

Comment: And can you try with Eclipse ADT? My experience is only with Eclipse IDE. If you have some questions with eclipse you can tell me.

Comment: No I can't because Android Studio (IntelliJ) is now the official Android IDE (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and the ADT is no longer in active development.

Comment: OK. You are correctly... So... try to see inside your intellyJ folder if exists an jdk and try to put this jdk in the path variable

Answer (score -2):

The path for android sdk is C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk but, it cannot be selected because... The folder AppData and its contence is in hidden attribute.. thus you need first need to remove tick from hidden checkbox