# Android SDK path not specified: SDK path is at empty folder

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[image]

I am facing the problem related to SDK's Path.

> C:\Users\SID\AppData\Local\Android : This folder is empty

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: specify SDK path will solve the problem

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28940222/9528391